# In Powershell append multiple comma deliminated lines in several files into a single xls spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell, parsing, split, scripting

I have several .txt files in a folder (no strict naming convention)..

```
server_stat_001.txt
server_stat_002.txt
server_stat_003.txt
etc.
```

.. where the following first 5 comma delimited lines look like this in EACH file:

```
top - 11:54:15 up 8 days, 21:28,  1 user,  load average: 0.76, 0.92, 0.94
Tasks: 458 total,   2 running, 456 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 16.3 us,  4.7 sy,  0.0 ni, 79.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 65805780 total, 40522964 free,  8392520 used, 16890296 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  6291452 total,  6291452 free,        0 used. 55605884 avail Mem
```

I would like to (for each file) capture the 5 line text block and convert as one single comma deleted record and append it into a common spreadsheet so that it looks like this.

[image: sample output spreadsheet with formatted text block from each file as a record]

My parsing skills are laughable right now, and any little advice would be most helpful.

Comment: If you want to improve your parsing skills you may watch this video about plain text parsing: [Sophisitcated Techniques of Plain Text Parsing](https://youtu.be/Hkzd8spCfCU)

Comment: Thanks @Olaf for the online tut. Made plenty of sense and simplified the crafting of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out thanks to the parser video suggested by @Olaf

```
# Source and Destination Data File Path
$ETL_FolderPath = "C:\cows\datafiles_in\TOP_DAPPS"
$ETL_DestinationFilePath = "C:\cows\datafiles_out\ETL-Files-TOP-DAPPS.csv"

# Build Arrays
$convertedLines = @()
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ETL_FolderPath -File

# String together the ugly block
foreach ($file in $files) {
$lines = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -TotalCount 5
$singleLine = $lines -join ","
$convertedLines += $singleLine
}

# Append each converted block as a record in a csv file for consumption
$convertedLines | Out-File -FilePath $ETL_DestinationFilePath -Append
```

This is a good basis for anything else I want to parse with a similar pattern and offset.

Comment: Cool. I'm glad it helped. If you're satisfied with your own solution you may mark it as the answer.  ;-)